# Does Feedburner send notifications about WordPress pages?

Tags: pages, feedburner

Does Feedburner send out notices about PAGES that are created or updated in WordPress, or just POSTS?

My client doesn't want emails going out about his PAGE content, but I can't find anything at Feedburner that states that it deals with POSTS only, not pages.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

By default, there is no feed for pages. So Feedburner doesn’t know if or when a page was created or updated.

If you didn’t set up a custom feed for pages Feedburner will not get this information.

Comment: Thank you! How would I know if I set up a custom feed for pages or not? Is there something I can look at in the account to indicate that?

I set the feed up for the domain name, and posts appear on the Home page, so I assume that does not count as a "page," right?

In other words, the Home page is what will feed into Feedburner, correct?

Comment: The default stream is just for posts. No pages, no attachments or custom post types. To add a second feed, you have to do this manually.